# Traceback errors when calling function

Tags: python

question: 
Define a function goguess() that implements a number guessing game as described below. Strategize as pair programmers. Then iteratively code and test.
In []: goguess()
I have a number between 1 and 20 inclusive.
Guess: 6
6 is too low.
Guess: 10
10 is too high.
Guess: 9
Right! My number is 9! You guessed in 3 guesses!

Code:

```
   from __future__ import print_function
import random
def goguess():
    guesses=0
    HighNumber = random.randint()
    LowNumber = random.randint()
    if LowNumber >= HighNumber:
        LowNumber = LowNumber - HighNumber
    answer = random.randint(LowNumber,HighNumber)
    print ('I have a number between', LowNumber, 'and', HighNumber, 'inclusive.')
    guess = raw_input("Guess:")
    while guess != answer:
        if guess < answer:
            print (guess, 'is too low')
            guess = raw_input("Guess:")
            guesses += 1
        elif guess > answer:
            print (guess, 'is too high')
            guess = raw_input("Guess:")
            guesses += 1
        else:
            print ('Right! My number is', answer, '!', 'You guessed in', guesses,  'guesses!')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in goguess
TypeError: randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call your random integer:

```
random.randint(1, 20)
```

IE you need `()`.  Otherwise you're assigning your variable to the function itself, not the result of calling the random integer function.

Comment: Not only that, but you also need to set the range, dont you?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
HighNumber = random.randint
```

you should have

```
HighNumber = random.randint(1,20) #Inclusive Range
```

This is because randint is a function, therefore it needs parentheses (and parameters in this case.)